# Will creating new instances in a Spring Singleton create memory leaks?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I'm currently maintaining an application and noticed that many of the objects that have been defined as Singleton in the Spring wiring create new instances of other objects in their methods.

For example there is a LoginService Singleton that creates a new instance of LoginDetails everytime the login() method is called. The LoginDetails are transient and are only required for the execution of the login() method.

My question is if Spring has created a single object for the LoginService how are instances of LoginDetails ever marked for garbage collection as a reference to the object that created them and used them is never terminated?

An example of what I mean is:

```
public void deleteCustomer(Long customerId, HttpServletRequest request) {

    CustomerType customerType = new CustomerType();
    customerType.setCustomerId(customerId);

    CustomerDeleteRequestType deleteRequest = new CustomerDeleteRequestType();
    deleteRequest.setCustomer(customerType);

    CustomerDeleteResponseType deleteResponse = mmmwsClient.executeRequest(deleteRequest);
    log.debug("Delete Response Recieved from Server for Customer Name Update " + deleteResponse.getServiceResult());

}
```

As the fields used are only method variables and not instance variables I guess the references to them would be destroyed when the method finishes?

Is my understanding of Spring Singleton correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the singleton doesn't maintain a reference to the objects it creates (by storing them in an instance field), and if no other reachable object maintain a reference to these objects, then they become unreachable, and the garbage collector collects them.

Who creates an object isn't important for the garbage collector. Who has a reference to an object is.

Comment: Thanks, my singleton class has no instance variables. The new objects are created and placed into and used by method fields only. Example updated in question(sorry should have included this in the first place):

Comment: A method is not a field. You don't place an object into a method. You use an object inside a method. A method is just logic. It doesn't hold any object in memory, except locally created object, but only during the execution of the method. When the method returns, if the object it has created is not referenced by any object, it's garbage collected.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess if it was an issue we'd have memory leaks all over the place! Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't understand the question, but it is late at night so bear with me.

I looked at [this](http://springtips.blogspot.com/2007/06/configuration-hell-remedy-with.html) page and it seems as though it does create a new instance every single time the method is called.

If you're using it like they are, a good replacement could be:

```
private static MessageResourceSingleton singleton;

public static MessageResourceSingleton getInstance() {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new MessageResourceSingleton();
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

I may not fully understand what you're getting at but if you could show us some examples of what you're using it would help **a lot**.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, I've updated the question