# `new` keyword in bean initialization in Spring Boot will cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, new-operator

We don't use `new` keyword to initialize new bean. But can I initialize new bean with `new` keyword like this

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

   @Bean(name = "qaDataSource")
   public JdbcTemplate customJdbcTemplate()  {

    DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .url("jdbc:postgresql://myserver:1111/dbName")
        .username(env.getProperty("spring.secondDatasource.username"))                
        .password(env.getProperty("spring.secondDatasource.password"))
        .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName"))
        .build();
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

Will `new` in this case cause any memory leaks?

Comment: You seem to have a very poor understanding on what constitutes a memory leak and how Spring's dependency injection works. Maybe you should read a Spring tutorial (about the DI part of it), then you'll understand better how it works internally.

Comment: @Kayaman you're right with a part of spring dependency injection, I need to understand it better. As to memory leaks, I have them a lot is my experience. Thanks for a reference to the part of the tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will creating new instances in a Spring Singleton create memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056550/will-creating-new-instances-in-a-spring-singleton-create-memory-leaks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will be no memory leak in this case.